# Efficient way to do a batch job in spring

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

The requirement is : To query the database everyday at say 10 pm.Based on the result set from DB,call several 3rd party services and perform some business operations and then complete the job.
What is the best possible way to achieve this in spring.will spring batch or spring batch integration be good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your steps it would be good that you will take a look into [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), too, and decide yourself what to be the best for you.

Spring Integration provides JDBC Inbound Channel Adapter, which really can poll DB using Cron Trigger. The result of the DB execution you really can to any other service, e.g. `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` or just generic `<service-activator>`. 
And even you can do some parallelism for several records from DB.

Not sure what you mean with "and then complete the job", but the work will be done automatically after the last records processed.

I think you really can come up with something similar using just Spring Batch, because there are really enough useful components, like to read DB, as well as implement your own to cal third party services.
Plus you can manage jobs via Repository.

To determine the difference and scope you should read manuals of both projects and decide yourself how to be further.

Comment: spring-batch-integration (a sub-project of spring-batch) provides a `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` which can be invoked by the service activator - thus combining the two projects - use SI to poll the DB then launch a batch job to process it.